# Best design pattern to wrap library specific objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm fairly new to design patterns.  What is the best pattern when a developer is using a library (in my case a library to screenscrape HTML) and doesn't want the client/calling classes to be 'stuck' to that library?

For example, if I am using an class in a library called HtmlPage, and a client says 'getPage()' - I don't want to return the HtmlPage Object from the library but some kind of wrapper of the HtmlPage that I can swap out if I decide to change libraries.  Is it as simple as this?  Or am I missing something?  Would I have to do this for every object in the library?

```
public class HtmlPageWrapper {
    private HtmlPage htmlPage;

    public HtmlPageWrapper(HtmlPage) {}

    public getTableOnPage() {
        return htmlPage.getTableOnPage;
    }

    // etc...

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're interested in the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). This will let you keep these third party classes away from your code by creating an `Adapter` class that exposes the abstract operations your application will use.

You don't necessarily have to do this for every object in the library, just make sure you wrap the main objects which you will need to interact with.

Comment: thanks, I thought that might be the one to use, but I thought that was only for bridging incompatible classes together... maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: that's the most common use case, but you can also use it in your scenario since in the future if you bring in a different html screenscraping library, then that library's interface might be incompatible with the current library and would therefore be incompatible with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would just extend it and override the ones I want to change/add, then I can reuse the ones I still like,

```
public class HtmlPageWrapper extends HtmlPage {

    public HtmlPageWrapper(HtmlPage p) {
         super(p);
    }

    @Override
    public getTableOnPage() {
        return super.getTableOnPage();
    }

    // etc...

}
```

Comment: Usually you need just a few methods, so as long as this is true composition might be better than inheretance.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Façade pattern if you want to hide the library behind a single interface, which can then have different implementations for different libraries.

Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. Façade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.

Ref: [Façade Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFacade.aspx)